# Java Collection of common supertype of two classes

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a method which takes as an argument a collection of some common supertype of two classes, `A` and `B` (and then adds instances of `A` and `B` to the collection). Something like the following:

```
public <T, A extends T, B extends T> void foo(Collection<T> collection);
```

Of course, that doesn't work since Java interprets A and B here as type parameters, overshadowing the concrete types `A` and `B`. Since I know the type hierarchy, I know the lowest common ancestor of `A` and `B`, say `C`, and can just have:

```
public void foo(Collection<? super C> collection);
```

I would rather not do this, though, since I very well might change the type hierarchy and would like `foo` to be as generic as possible.

Comment: No, there's no general way to do this better than what you have.

Comment: Why are you resistant to your solution?  When designing API's with generic parameters there is a "Producer extends, Consumer super" principle.  Since your method consumes `C` instances, `super` is the logical way to use a wildcard in your API and have your method be as flexible as possible.